# Nested Collection Mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, nested, automapper

Am trying to map nested collections using automapper and I have done the basic setup and configuration. When I try to do the map it the **nested values are coming as null**.  I have tried to follow few posts and put together something. I want the list to have a hierarchy instead of flattening. Any help around this would be great.

**Source Entities:**

```
public class OuterEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InnerEntity> InnerEntityList { get; set; }
}

public class InnerEntity
{
    public int InnerId { get; set; }
    public string InnerName { get; set; }
    public List<InnerMostEntity> InnerMostList { get; set; }
}

public class InnerMostEntity
{
    public int InnerMostId { get; set; }
    public string InnerMostName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Destination Entities:**

```
public class OuterEntityDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InnerEntity> InnerEntityList { get; set; }
}

public class InnerEntityDTO
{
    public int InnerId { get; set; }
    public string InnerName { get; set; }
    public List<InnerMostEntity> InnerMostList { get; set; }
}

public class InnerMostEntityDTO
{
    public int InnerMostId { get; set; }
    public string InnerMostName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
public List<OuterEntityDTO> GetAll()
{

var outerEntityList = myRepo.GetAll(); //Type of List<OuterEntity>  

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<OuterEntity, OuterEntityDTO>().ReverseMap();
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerEntity, InnerEntityDTO>().ReverseMap();
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerMostEntity, InnerMostEntityDTO>().ReveseMap();
});

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var innerMostDTO = Mapper.Map<List<OuterEntity>,List<OuterEntityDTO>>(outerEntityList);

//The inner list at first level itself is null.
return innerMostDTO;
}
```

Am trying to achieve this in DOT NET Core. Autommaper version is 6.1.1

Comment: are the source objects populated (lazy loading)?

Comment: Yes the source objects are populated. Not really sure why the mapping is not happening.

Comment: The issue is now resolved and it was a miss from my end. The List names were different in both entities and after reading through few SO queries, I understood that the name of the properties should be same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a wrong class hierarchy in DTO classes, as you have

```
public List<InnerMostEntity> InnerMostList { get; set; }
```

in public class InnerEntityDTO, you should write it as

```
public List<InnerMostEntityDTO> InnerMostList { get; set; }
```